# How do I make a spellcasting item that doesn't require a mage or a sleepless person to maintain it?

Tags: magic-items, crafting, anima-beyond-fantasy

So let's say I want to make an Infinite Bag, for carrying all the stuff in.

My GM has ruled that I cannot give an item ZR (and thus I cannot use the "Spellcasting Item" table, as that requires someone to provide Zeon), so I turn to the Automatic Spell table...

Except that *appears* to require an interaction every hour to maintain the spell (even if I buy No Limits), which is only doable if you don't actually sleep.

Is this how that rule works?  Is there any way I can produce the effect I want short of going to the 'GM fiat' table?

Comment: While that edit is technically still well within the thrust of my original question, @lithas, I'm going to revise it back to the broader interpretation.  It's not just Infinite Bags that need refreshing too often.

Comment: This stack works best with specific answers to specific problems. It's totally your prerogative to widen that question, but be warned that you're less likely to attract good answers with broad questions